# How to have the class="selected" depending on what the current page/url is

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

This is my first post so forgive as I am just new in the world of web development.

Normally, when I try to make a website, I create a file called header.html and footer.html so that I only change data once in all of the pages rather than having multiple same headers on many html files. And include them all in a php file together with the content and the php codes that comes per page.

Now my problem is because I only have 1 header, the css is designed in a way that whatever the current menu/tab is, it will be marked as "selected" so that its obvious to the user what page they are currently in.

My question is how do I solve this problem:

1.) To have the `class="selected"` depending on what the current page/url is.

```
<!--Menu Starts-->
        <div class="menu">
            <div id="smoothmenu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php" class="selected">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="features.php">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="support1.php">Support 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="support2.php">Support 2</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
<!-- Menu Ends--!>
```

Thank You :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for a non-javascript / php approach...

First you need to determine which nav-link should be set as active and then add the *selected* class. The code would look something like this

**HTML within php file**

Call a php function inline within the hyperlink `<a>` markup passing in the links destination request uri

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("about")?>>About</a> </li>
    <li><a href="services.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("services")?>>Services</a> </li>
    <li><a href="features.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("features")?>>Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="support1.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("support1")?>>Support 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="support2.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("support2")?>>Support 2</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**PHP function**

The php function simply needs to compare the passed in request uri and if it matches the current page being rendered output the *selected* class

```
<?php
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'class="selected"';
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 for encapsulating all the code in the header and supplying a non-javascript approach.

Comment: @Chris Moutray Omg! thanks for this :) , really helped! I made a new include file called config.php and included this code. It solved my problem. I Always found stackoverflow as a really helpful community to go to :) Thank again to all.

Answer (score 1):

Give each link a separate id then use jQuery on the individual pages.

```
 <li><a href="index.php" id="home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.php" id="about">About</a> </li>
 <li><a href="services.php" id="services">Services</a> </li>
 <li><a href="features.php" id="features">Features</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="support">Support</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="support1.php">Support 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="support2.php">Support 2</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
```

On the services page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#services").addClass("selected");
});
```

Or even better as robertc pointed out in the comments, there is no need to even bother with the id's just make the jquery this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[href='services.php']").addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: No need to clutter up with IDs: `$("[href='services.php']").addClass("selected");`

Comment: Good point, never really thought of that, still a bit new to jQuery myself. I'll add it as an option, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could ID each link and use JavaScript/Jquery to add the `selected` class to the appropriate link.

```
<!--Menu Starts-->
        <div class="menu">
            <div id="smoothmenu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li id="home-page"><a href="index.php" class="selected">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="about-page"><a href="about.php">About</a> </li>
                    <li id="services-page"><a href="services.php">Services</a> </li>
                    <li id="features-page"><a href="features.php">Features</a></li>
                    <li id="support-page"><a href="#">Support</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="support1-page"><a href="support1.php">Support 1</a></li>
                            <li id="support2-page"><a href="support2.php">Support 2</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
<!-- Menu Ends--!>
```

On your content page use jQuery to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#features-page").addClass("selected");
});
```

Another method you could use is:

[Add class element based on the name of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943417/add-class-element-based-on-the-name-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

One variant on Chris's approach is to output a particular class to identify the page, for example on the `body` element, and then use fixed classes on the menu items, and a CSS rule that targets them matching. For example, this page:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <title>I'm the about page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
         .about .about,
         .index .index,
         .services .services,
         .features .features {
           font-weight: bold;
         }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="<?php echo basename(__FILE__, ".php"); ?>">
  This is a menu:
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php" class="about">About</a> </li>
    <li><a href="services.php" class="services">Services</a> </li>
    <li><a href="features.php" class="features">Features</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

...is pretty light on dynamic code, but should achieve the objective; if you save it as "about.php", then the About link will be bold, but if you save it as "services.php", then the Services link will be bold, etc.

If your code structure suits it, you might be able to simply hardcode the page's `body` class in the page's template file, rather than using any dynamic code for it. This approach effectively gives you a way of moving the "logic" for the menu system out of the menu code, which will always remain the same for every page, and up to a higher level.

As an added bonus, you can now use pure CSS to target other things based on the page you're on. For example, you could turn all the `h1` elements on the `index.php` page red just using more CSS:

```
 .index h1 { color: red; }
```

Comment: thanks for the follow up info :) , really helped as I never knew this before. I will try this with my current project. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from simple if and PHP page / basename() function..

```
<!--Menu Starts-->
    <div class="menu">
        <div id="smoothmenu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "index.php") { ?> class="selected" <?php } ?>>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php" <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "about.php") { ?> class="selected" <?php } ?>>About</a> </li>
                <li><a href="services.php" <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "services.php") { ?> class="selected" <?php } ?>>Services</a> </li>
                <li><a href="features.php" <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "features.php") { ?> class="selected" <?php } ?>>Features</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English, however may be it could help. You can use jQuery for this task. For this you need to match the page url to the anchor of menu and then add class selected to it. for example the jQuery code would be

```
    jQuery('[href='+currentURL+']').addClass('selected');
```