# Visited menu option is not getting highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So i've been looking at this jquery plugin that highlights the current menu item depnding on the current page. I currently want the menu items border and text to change color. The CSS method i'm trying to achieve this in is .selected I'm probably being really silly here, however i can't seem to get it working. Any help would be really appreciated. My JS is countained in a seperate folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pageMenu.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="site-header">
        <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
           <nav id="nav"<a href="#"></a>
       <ul id="site-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">Used Cars</a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="aboutus.php">About us</a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#site-nav a').each(function(index) {
    if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
        $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

finally the CSS (which i know is a mess)

```
#site-nav {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1;
}

#site-nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
}

#site-nav li a:link, #site-nav li a:visited {
font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
padding: 12px 17px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
/* horizontal radius / vertical radius */
list-style: none;
border-style: outset;
border-width: 1px;
background: #FFFFFF;
background: rgba(226, 226, 226, 1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219,      219, 219, 1) 3%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1)), color-stop(3%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 3%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 3%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 3%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 3%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#fefefe', GradientType=0);
}

 #site-nav a:focus, #site-nav a:hover {
color: #DC2F35;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.selected {
color: #DC2F35;
border-color: #DC2F35;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post this in a jsfiddle? What is actually happening instead of the intended behavior?

Comment: Seems to [work fine in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djv3ozk9/1/) (notice I changed the link address of one of them so it would get selected). Try opening the console (ctrl+alt+j on chrome), are you getting any errors? Perhaps you didn't import your javascript files correctly...

Comment: it works fine when i use # as i'm not linking to a new page. As soon as i navigate from index.php to aboutus.php, about us in the nav bar doesnt seem to pick up the formatting from .selected It works on index.php but thats it

Comment: Because of the way jsfiddle works, the domain changes with each update, so here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/djv3ozk9/5/) that should work after you press "run" one time (this isn't anything to do with your code). I also restyled your links to be more modern (I did it for fun, you can copy my design, but don't get confused by it it's completely inconsequential!)

Comment: @user3697474 so your problem is probably that you're not importing your script or your css file into aboutus.php. Again, can you open up the console and tell me if you see any errors?

Comment: Yeah as you stated before, i hadn't linked the links correctly. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your condition of if block, Since JavaScript does not allow you to compare string using == operator. You have to use localeCompare() function to compare string .
Eg:- 
var str1 = "cd";
var str2 = "ab";
var n = str1.localeCompare(str2);

For any further information you can see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be adding the selected class in the php that builds the menu. This would prevent any [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) on your page.

I don't know if this is bad form but I'm going to link you to this answer:
[How to have the class="selected" depending on what the current page/url is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774962/how-to-have-the-class-selected-depending-on-what-the-current-page-url-is)

Answer (score 0):

As expected, i was in fact being silly. The code works, however i didn't link the javascript correctly in my other files